# Frequent configuration messages on Samsung J5

Tags: samsung, notifications, samsung-galaxy-j5

I am getting some configuration messages frequently and have no idea what it is. How can I prevent it? 
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This comes from your service provider. Call them.